# argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used - GSUB()

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following problem.

```
table <- data.frame(col1 = c("cars1 gm", "cars2 gl"), col2 = c("cars1 motor mel", "cars2 prom del"))

      col1            col2
1 cars1 gm cars1 motor mel
2 cars2 gl  cars2 prom del

table$word <- gsub(table$col1, ' ', table$col2) 

Warning message:  In gsub(table$col1, " ", table$col2) :  argument
'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How do I create a new column called `word` containing only those values of `col2` which do not appear in `col1`?

```
      col1            col2       word
1 cars1 gm cars1 motor mel  motor mel
2 cars2 gl  cars2 prom del   prom del
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to build your lookup and then `sapply` over columns to perform the `gsub` of interest:

```
table$col1 <- gsub(" ", "|", table$col1)
table$word <- sapply(1:nrow(table), function(x) gsub(table$col1[x], "", table$col2[x]))

table
#      col1            col2       word
#1 cars1|gm cars1 motor mel  motor mel
#2 cars2|gl  cars2 prom del   prom del
```

---

Using a similar idea as the above answer but using `mapply` instead of `sapply`:

```
table$word <- mapply(function(x, y) gsub( gsub(" ", "|", x), "", y),
                                    table$col1,
                                    table$col2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mapply`,

```
#Make sure you read your data with stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
table<-data.frame(col1=c("cars1 gm","cars2 gl"),
                  col2=c("cars1 motor mel", "cars2 prom del"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table$word <- mapply(function(x, y) 
                     trimws(gsub(sapply(strsplit(x, ' '), paste, collapse = '|'), '', y)), 
                     table$col1, table$col2)
table
#      col1            col2      word
#1 cars1 gm cars1 motor mel motor mel
#2 cars2 gl  cars2 prom del  prom del
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply`, `paste` and `strsplit` like this.

```
table$word <- mapply(function(x, y) paste(y[!(y %in% x)], collapse=" "),
                     strsplit(as.character(table$col1), split=" "),
                     strsplit(as.character(table$col2), split=" "))
```

Here, `strsplit` splits a character vector on " " and returns a list. These two lists are fed to `mapply` which checks corresponding values of each list and returns values of the second list that are not in the first. The resulting vector is pasted together with `paste` and its collapse argument.

which returns

```
table
      col1            col2      word
1 cars1 gm cars1 motor mel motor mel
2 cars2 gl  cars2 prom del  prom del
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings in `col1` and `col2`, as the words may not be in the same order, and then you can select the words than only appear in `col2` using `setdiff`:

```
table$word=sapply(1:nrow(table),function(i)
paste(setdiff(unlist(strsplit(table$col2[i]," ")),
unlist(strsplit(table$col1[i]," "))),collapse=" "))
```

This returns:

```
col1            col2      word
1 cars1 gm cars1 motor mel motor mel
2 cars2 gl  cars2 prom del  prom del
```